# Label points in a circle plot R

Tags: r

Is there a way to show the numbers that correspond to a point on a circle? I read up on the text(xy) function but it is for scatter plots which this is not. The scripts is as follows and the image attached shows what the result is. I would like to identify the point in the plots. Any help rendered is appreciated! Thanks.

```
library (circular)
df<- read.csv("Direction.csv", header = TRUE)
df1 <- df [ which(df$Month==1 & df$Day>0 & df$Day <32) ,]
df2 <- df1[c(-1,-2,-3)]
df3<- lapply(df2, function(df2) circular(df2, units='degrees', template='geographics'))
dens<- lapply(df3, density.circular, bw =5)
par(mfrow=c(5,4), oma=c(2,1.3,2,2), mar=c(1.5,2,2,1), tcl=-0.2, mgp=c(0,1,0))
titles <- c("1000mb", "925mb", "850mb", "700mb", "600mb", "500mb", "400mb", "300mb", 
            "250mb", "200mb", "150mb", "100mb","70mb", "50mb", "30mb", "20mb", "10mb")
for(i in 1:17){
  plot(mean(df3[[1]]), main = titles[1],) 
  print(mean(df3[[1]]))
  print(var(df3[[1]]))
  print(summary(df3[[1]]))
}
dput(df3[1])
structure(list(X1000mb = structure(c(86L, 130L, 75L, 59L, 56L, 
69L, 139L, 358L, 98L, 175L, 322L, 17L, 336L, 46L, 137L, 1L, 2L, 
102L, 225L, 121L, 179L, 291L, 325L, 317L, 321L, 349L, 28L, 38L, 
36L, 117L, 144L, 73L, 121L, 135L, 131L, 127L, 139L, 167L, 298L, 
213L, 37L, 33L, 71L, 120L, 156L, 14L, 51L, 92L, 168L, 332L, 24L, 
71L, 128L, 98L, 104L, 86L, 155L, 5L, 281L, 342L, 356L, 346L, 
210L, 186L, 199L, 133L, 191L, 282L, 139L, 168L, 158L, 154L, 117L, 
149L, 162L, 157L, 192L, 175L, 197L, 171L, 184L, 305L, 70L, 169L, 
207L, 8L, 72L, 134L, 160L, 135L, 154L, 149L, 161L, 182L, 259L, 
173L, 205L, 331L, 112L, 26L, 129L, 137L, 120L, 136L, 156L, 327L, 
332L, 349L, 16L, 28L, 42L, 352L, 94L, 149L, 153L, 183L, 183L, 
196L, 170L, 164L, 212L, 169L, 180L, 206L, 81L, 135L, 145L, 148L, 
172L, 174L, 160L, 188L, 193L, 197L, 247L, 68L, 181L, 177L, 219L, 
204L, 86L, 333L, 354L, 132L, 0L, 35L, 27L, 38L, 77L, 123L, 174L, 
172L, 191L, 312L, 307L, 29L, 161L, 62L, 104L, 240L, 300L, 292L, 
194L, 202L, 274L, 349L, 26L, 198L, 294L, 185L, 178L, 324L, 28L, 
36L, 93L, 115L, 280L, 24L, 353L, 348L, 68L, 24L, 357L, 17L, 47L, 
45L, 238L, 333L, 342L, 111L, 233L, 183L, 193L, 212L, 188L, 164L, 
142L, 158L, 179L, 300L, 336L, 297L, 346L, 17L, 149L, 115L, 8L, 
358L, 341L, 22L, 142L, 283L, 349L, 273L, 271L, 224L, 313L, 62L, 
100L, 137L, 158L, 235L, 155L, 184L, 132L, 153L, 206L, 182L, 187L, 
238L, 275L, 292L, 1L, 36L, 148L, 334L, 30L, 58L, 356L, 6L, 345L, 
91L, 157L, 332L, 327L, 11L, 170L, 169L, 120L, 158L, 160L, 177L, 
168L, 300L, 295L, 7L, 75L, 172L, 328L, 3L, 63L, 348L, 34L, 185L, 
347L, 66L, 105L, 130L, 151L, 83L, 120L, 154L, 172L, 152L, 174L, 
174L, 159L, 147L, 173L, 212L, 327L, 55L, 203L, 192L, 95L, 139L, 
200L, 227L, 209L, 262L, 129L, 151L, 200L, 133L, 190L, 112L, 85L, 
184L, 185L, 186L, 256L, 28L, 157L, 54L, 55L, 88L, 315L, 27L, 
53L, 126L, 179L, 161L, 163L, 168L, 280L, 336L, 89L, 175L, 253L, 
357L, 250L, 36L, 62L, 103L, 1L, 5L, 55L, 97L, 114L, 143L, 156L, 
156L, 178L, 183L, 191L, 285L, 4L, 16L, 69L, 340L, 63L, 131L, 
128L, 137L, 137L, 253L, 213L, 165L, 166L, 166L, 171L, 193L, 186L, 
180L, 194L, 255L, 294L, 60L, 175L, 123L, 136L, 147L, 144L, 146L, 
135L, 157L, 228L, 177L, 165L, 168L, 176L, 182L, 352L, 23L, 260L, 
298L, 283L, 152L, 151L, 180L, 170L, 2L, 60L, 121L, 110L, 153L, 
174L, 204L, 312L, 153L, 250L, 223L, 244L, 345L, 225L, 233L, 289L, 
212L, 190L, 285L, 226L, 136L, 111L, 179L, 200L, 274L, 2L, 351L, 
10L, 12L, 13L, 340L, 336L, 331L, 258L, 36L, 95L, 117L, 149L, 
151L, 155L, 135L, 187L, 191L, 195L, 15L, 103L, 161L, 194L, 186L, 
167L, 90L, 174L, 205L, 173L, 208L, 197L, 217L, 246L, 151L, 161L, 
119L, 128L, 159L, 232L, 198L, 227L, 175L, 213L, 220L, 226L, 171L, 
244L, 203L, 167L, 185L, 156L, 182L, 157L, 154L, 144L, 146L, 174L, 
196L, 141L, 348L, 22L, 63L, 125L, 163L, 32L, 331L, 19L, 72L, 
85L, 186L, 297L, 353L, 32L, 242L, 240L, 191L, 200L, 192L, 208L, 
256L, 193L, 243L, 3L, 18L, 293L, 357L, 233L, 169L, 160L, 189L, 
310L, 305L, 288L, 201L, 334L, 56L, 274L, 269L, 303L, 237L, 224L, 
230L, 170L, 192L, 135L, 194L, 132L, 122L, 149L, 171L, 199L, 217L, 
133L, 172L, 195L, 329L, 11L, 48L, 120L, 158L, 198L, 23L, 109L, 
154L, 145L, 86L, 41L, 156L, 186L, 222L, 150L, 163L, 19L, 278L, 
325L, 352L, 5L, 72L, 136L, 123L, 149L, 154L, 132L, 155L, 233L, 
187L, 168L, 9L, 41L, 262L, 4L, 40L, 154L, 157L, 233L, 97L, 162L, 
171L, 171L, 181L, 355L, 35L, 103L, 214L, 355L, 335L, 345L, 13L, 
331L, 347L, 323L, 294L, 234L, 295L, 190L, 151L, 182L, 231L, 268L, 
286L, 20L, 11L, 144L, 181L, 149L, 160L, 180L, 343L, 65L, 130L, 
108L, 166L, 164L, 182L, 160L, 174L, 101L, 27L, 62L, 110L, 76L, 
25L, 150L, 173L, 169L, 183L, 181L, 189L, 167L, 232L, 345L, 154L, 
216L, 195L, 212L, 242L, 289L, 252L, 111L, 148L, 161L, 159L, 153L, 
162L, 139L, 158L, 150L, 164L, 198L, 14L, 141L, 156L, 288L, 355L, 
36L, 73L, 208L, 215L, 323L, 135L, 188L, 289L, 232L, 227L, 317L, 
222L, 192L, 76L, 40L, 172L, 157L, 142L, 216L, 223L, 163L, 237L, 
344L, 30L, 126L, 143L, 162L, 162L, 104L, 103L, 123L, 110L, 140L, 
146L, 149L, 139L, 161L, 194L, 187L, 283L, 13L, 16L, 185L, 177L, 
200L, 155L, 152L, 169L, 238L, 282L, 161L, 185L, 224L, 198L, 159L, 
208L, 309L, 179L, 182L, 244L, 290L, 217L, 236L, 20L, 61L, 130L, 
162L, 262L, 245L, 206L, 225L, 193L, 331L, 34L, 133L, 216L, 277L, 
343L, 300L, 342L, 15L, 50L, 307L, 314L, 5L, 24L, 19L, 86L, 120L, 
356L, 34L, 19L, 346L, 359L, 25L, 45L, 97L, 151L, 67L, 100L, 23L, 
66L, 9L, 223L, 121L, 164L, 175L, 174L, 217L, 227L, 241L, 184L, 
265L, 196L, 215L, 178L, 326L, 102L, 339L, 21L, 43L, 19L, 65L, 
289L, 288L, 94L, 97L, 132L, 123L, 141L, 141L, 282L, 220L, 281L, 
202L, 252L, 225L, 350L, 77L, 199L, 274L, 209L, 229L, 5L, 67L, 
19L, 28L, 56L, 89L, 71L, 68L, 126L, 120L, 124L, 112L, 83L, 171L, 
25L, 306L, 305L, 338L, 3L, 319L, 12L, 70L, 19L, 185L, 199L, 88L, 
140L, 176L, 207L, 149L, 155L, 162L, 152L, 164L, 178L, 201L, 214L, 
169L, 175L, 180L, 168L, 183L, 163L, 186L, 257L, 223L, 166L, 157L, 
133L, 24L, 115L, 162L, 173L, 245L, 147L, 105L, 81L, 75L, 75L, 
47L, 27L, 15L, 347L, 21L, 116L, 160L, 178L, 193L, 51L, 232L, 
295L, 358L, 311L, 16L, 17L, 7L, 47L, 345L, 4L, 36L, 118L, 209L, 
173L, 231L, 8L, 90L, 156L, 237L, 163L, 343L, 350L, 354L, 36L, 
62L, 45L, 43L, 95L, 113L, 164L, 317L, 315L, 168L, 188L, 190L, 
168L, 227L, 185L, 142L, 249L, 200L, 228L, 7L, 50L, 95L, 265L, 
10L, 75L, 63L, 151L, 124L, 146L, 35L, 303L, 331L, 218L, 303L, 
312L, 341L, 33L, 36L, 9L, 74L, 85L, 105L, 99L, 101L, 91L, 130L, 
152L, 14L, 211L, 271L, 319L, 315L, 309L, 358L, 31L), circularp = structure(list(
    type = "angles", units = "degrees", template = "geographics", 
    modulo = "asis", zero = 1.5707963267949, rotation = "clock"), .Names = c("type", 
"units", "template", "modulo", "zero", "rotation")), class = c("circular", 
"integer"))), .Names = "X1000mb")
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your example complete - right now, it doesn't plot your circles. Include the output of `dput(df3)` in your code. Even better, cut your example down to a single picture to make your example [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @StephanKolassa you asked for it and it shall be put in. It is very long and a list so here you go!

Comment: @Gunnerfan, Please show the code you used to produce the plot in your post, given the `dput`ed data.

Comment: @Henrik...it is edited to show that

Comment: @Gunnerfan, The data preparation steps are not very relevant. Again, please show the _plot command_ which can be used **on the `dput`ed data**.

Comment: @Henrik The _plot command_ used are included unless I am not understanding your statement. `plot(mean(df3[[1]]), main = titles[1],)` is the command. What _plot command_ are you asking for?

Comment: `plot(mean(thenameofyourdputeddata), main = titles[1])`; `Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values` `In addition: Warning messages:`

Comment: Sorry, I give up. For next time: please read these links on **minimal, self contained examples**: [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [**here**](http://www.sscce.org/), [**here**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html), and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Comment: @Henrik The name of the dputed data is df3[1] which is included there. Thanks for the time taken, it is still appreciated. Your questions asked is not straightforward. The answer below is actually related to the question asked which has to do with labelling plots.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter that it's not strictly a "scatterplot" .  Now that you've set up an array of subplots, you can cycle thru them again, but this time using `text()` to place data at the desired location within each subplot.  Roughly,

```
for (i in 1:17 )  text(x_loc[i],y_loc[i], some_text_vector[i])
```

Where you've "preloaded" the text strings and locations.

Comment: going by your statement, I tried this `for (i in 1:17 )  text(df3[i],df3[i])`but I get 
`Error in xy.coords(x, y, recycle = TRUE) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Comment: Then fix your inputs so you're not feeding a `list` object where numbers are needed.  `text(df3[i])` most likely is not doing what you think it is.